# Stored Procedure to Insert Data from one table to another with same column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have one master table and few smaller table.

- `Master` table has `C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 |`
- A small table has `C1 | C2 | C3 |`

Also `@C1` (a variable that has a value which matches the value of C1 in `Master` table.

The column names matches for both table. I want to create a stored procedure which inserts values from `Master` table (`C1`, `C2`, and `C3`) to smaller table (`C1, C2, C3`).

My effort:

```
Create proc Schema.Proc
(@C1 int)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SmallTable
(C1, C2, C3) --- Columns of smaller table
Values (SELECT C1, C2, C3 ---Columns of Master table
FROM MasterTable)
WHERE C1 = @C1 --- Where value of C1 of Master table matches the value of @C1
END
```

Please help

Thank you

Comment: You didn't explain why you chocked. And, I'm removing the [tag:jQuery] tag

Comment: Are you offering bonus points for a solution using jQuery?

Comment: Thanks guys for a quick help. Sorry for the jquery tag...hehe I will make the necessary changes and mark the first answer as ACCEPTED as soon as I can. Thank you

Comment: haha - that's too bad, it could have been rather interesting

Comment: Just want to clarify- is the C1 column here your foreign key reference between the Master table and the smaller table?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the `INSERT INTO ...  SELECT .....` syntax - no `VALUES` keyword involved:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Schema.Proc
   (@C1 int)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SmallTable(C1, C2, C3) --- Columns of smaller table
        SELECT C1, C2, C3 ---Columns of Master table
        FROM MasterTable
        WHERE C1 = @C1 --- Where value of C1 of Master table matches the value of @C1
END
```

Answer (score 3):

You were close! As long as C1, C2 and C3 are the same data types this should work.

```
Create proc Schema.Proc
(@C1 int)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SmallTable
(C1, C2, C3) --- Columns of smaller table
SELECT C1, C2, C3 ---Columns of Master table
FROM MasterTable
WHERE C1 = @C1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_INSERT(U_ID NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO X(ID,NAME,SALARY)--X IS TABLE NAME 
SELECT ABC_ID,NAME,SALARY FROM ABC
WHERE ABC_ID=U_ID;--ABC_ID IS SAME VALUE OF U_ID
END;
```