# Syntax to copy a data from one table to another table using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Syntax to copy data from one table to another table, when data are inserted into master table using stored procedure. eg: I have registration table it contains name, password, confirm password, email etc. When user inserts data into registration table, that time the user name and password are copied into login table.

Comment: refer this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204834/stored-procedure-to-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-with-same-column-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Trigger?**  By "stored procedure" did you mean trigger?  Automatically updating your login table every time somebody adds a record the the registration table sounds like a trigger: you can read up about triggers here:  http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i

**Stored Proc** I don't know if stored procs make sense for you, but if they do the link below in Transactions has some examples.

You could (should?) insert into the login table the same way you end up inserting them into your "master" registration table; use two INSERT statements.  If you're *not* using a stored procedure to insert into the "master" table I have a hard time seeing how adding a stored proc benefits you.  Either way (e.g. doing it with a stored procedure or some kind of dynamic SQL / prepared statement) you're going to want to use another insert statement for the "secondary" table (even if that 2nd insert statement lives in a trigger).

**Transactions** You also should read up on transaction boundaries so you can commit (or roll back) your updates to each table: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions  (transactions will help you avoid getting stuck with a record in on table but missing from the other; they all write 100% or nothing writes).

**Referential Integrity**  You also might want to read up on referential integrity; add constraints to your "login" table so that only login names that exist in the master table can be used in your login table.
http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2000/referential-integrity-sql-server

I mentioned triggers, transactions, and referential integrity because from your question it sounds like you might be at the beginning of your SQL learning curve and *may* not know what you don't yet know.  Good luck.

Comment: Why do you store Confirm Password in your Registration Table ?

Comment: My guess would be the original poster wants new people to automatically be logged in without having to go and re-type their userid and password (which I would find refreshing from most website design).  I also guess they wouldn't replicate all of the columns from Registration table to the Login table.